# how can I import array prototype functions into my project

Tags: javascript, import, prototype

So I have written a bunch of functions on arrays to use throughout my project. My functions are something simple like this

```
Array.prototype.mySort == function(){
    return this.sort((a,b) => a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1)
}
```

I have them all written in a separate file called `array-helper-functions`

Now I want to be able to use them in other files like this

```
const transformedArray = myArray.map(something).mySort().filter(somethingElse)
```

how could I export them in source file and import them ?

Comment: Just include the js file in your webpage...

Comment: Is your project using simple script files or any module bundler like webpack or parcel?

Comment: It's actually a react project, so yes, webpack is there

Answer (score 1):

If your JS runs on NodeJS, then you can create a function like this:

```
function initializeArrayFunctions() {
    Array.prototype.mySort = function(){
        return this.sort((a,b) => a.text < b.text ? -1 : 1)
    }
}

export default initializeArrayFunctions;
```

and then you can `import` it and call it in the other file. If your JS is running in the browser, then you will need a `script` tag with its `src` being the correct path to the file you intend to load.